# Rolling Hash algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like any ideas or suggestions on how to enhance the code for [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) algorithm and make if faster. Even if it is a change in one line. I tried to add a list, because I thought it would be more efficient, but it didn't work properly. So any ideas on how to enhance it. I would appreciate the assist.

```
import time


class RollingHash:
def __init__(self, text, sizeWord):
    self.text = text
    self.hash = 0
    self.sizeWord = sizeWord

    for i in range(0, sizeWord):
        # ord maps the character to a number
        # subtract out the ASCII value of "a" to start the indexing at zero
        self.hash += (ord(self.text[i]) - ord("a") + 1) * (26 ** (sizeWord - i - 1))  # change the first / with *

    # start index of current window
    self.window_start = 0
    # end of index window
    self.window_end = sizeWord

def move_window(self):
    if self.window_end <= len(self.text) - 1:
        # remove left letter from hash value
        self.hash -= (ord(self.text[self.window_start]) - ord("a") + 1) * 26 ** (self.sizeWord - 1)
        self.hash *= 26
        self.hash += ord(self.text[self.window_end]) - ord("a") + 1
        self.window_start += 1
        self.window_end += 1

def window_text(self):
    return self.text[self.window_start:self.window_end]


def rabin_karp(word, text):
if word == "" or text == "":
    return None
if len(word) > len(text):
    return None

rolling_hash = RollingHash(text, len(word))
word_hash = RollingHash(word, len(word))
# word_hash.move_window()

for i in range(len(text) - len(word) + 1):
    if rolling_hash.hash == word_hash.hash:
        if rolling_hash.window_text() == word:
            print(i)
    rolling_hash.move_window()
return  'Pattern length: ' , len(word)



text = input("Text: ")
word = input("Pattern: ")
t1 = time.clock()
results = rabin_karp(word, text)
print(results)
t2 = time.clock()
print('Run Time:  %0.5f ms' % ((t2 - t1) * 1000.0))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! What Python version are you using?

Comment: (3.x, guessing from `print()`.)

Comment: I am using version 3.6.2.

Comment: See also: [Karp-Rabin String Matching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/70066/93149), [Rabin Karp algorithm improvement for string contains A to Z only](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/154224/93149), and [Text search in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147423/93149) for an idea how to avoid  adverse effects with longer *word*s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as a decent compiler would: precompute some expressions, and reduce the "strength" of others.
For worse rather than better, most opportunities for this are in the constructor.
Part of the performance of on object depends on its interface - I've included an alternative function that finds the (position of the) next match, if any.
Benchmarking is difficult, micro or not: beware "printing" and use help.

```
import timeit


class RollingHash:
    '''A rolling hash for a window of constant length into a text,
        both specified at construction.
    '''
    adjust = ord("a") - 1
    alphabet = 26

    def __init__(self, text, size_word):
        '''Set up a rolling hash for a window of size_word into text.'''
        self.text = text
        if len(text) < size_word:
            self.hash = None
            return
        rk = 0
        for c in text[:size_word]:
            rk = rk * self.alphabet + ord(c) - self.adjust
        self.hash = rk
        self.pos = -1
        self.window_start = 0
        self.window_end = size_word
        self.multiplier = RollingHash.alphabet ** (size_word - 1)

    def move_window(self):
        '''Advance window by one position.'''
        if self.window_end < len(self.text):
            # remove left letter from hash value
            self.hash = \
                (self.hash - (ord(self.text[self.window_start])
                              - RollingHash.adjust) * self.multiplier) \
                * RollingHash.alphabet \
                + ord(self.text[self.window_end]) - RollingHash.adjust
            self.window_start += 1
            self.window_end += 1

    def window_text(self):
        '''Return current window text.'''
        return self.text[self.window_start:self.window_end]

    def match(self, other):
        '''Return position of next match, or none.'''
        roll = self.hash
        text = self.text
        # "local copies" may help or hinder readability and performance
        start = self.window_start
        end = self.window_end
        limit = len(self.text)
        result = None
        while end < limit:
            if self.pos < other.hash == roll \
                and other.text == text[start:end] \
                and self.pos < start:
                result = self.pos = start
                break;
            roll = (roll - (ord(text[start])
                            - RollingHash.adjust) * self.multiplier) \
                * RollingHash.alphabet \
                + ord(text[end]) - RollingHash.adjust
            start += 1
            end += 1
        self.window_start = start
        self.window_end = end
        return result


verbose = True

def rabin_karp(word, text):
    '''Print indexes of matches for word in text.'''
    if word == "" or text == "":
        return None
    size_word = len(word)
    if size_word > len(text):
        return None

    rolling_hash = RollingHash(text, size_word)
    word_hash = RollingHash(word, size_word)

    for i in range(len(text) - size_word + 1):
        if rolling_hash.hash == word_hash.hash:
            if rolling_hash.window_text() == word:
                if verbose:
                    print(i)
            else:
                print(rolling_hash.window_text(), '<>', word, "at", i)
        rolling_hash.move_window()
    return 'Pattern length: ', size_word


def karp_rabin(word, text):
    '''Print indexes of matches for word in text.'''
    size_word = len(word)
    if not 0 < size_word <= len(text):
        return None

    rolling_hash = RollingHash(text, size_word)
    word_hash = RollingHash(word, size_word)

    while True:
        position = rolling_hash.match(word_hash)
        if position is None:
            return 'Pattern length: ', size_word
        if verbose:
            print(position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = input("Text: ")
    word = input("Pattern: ")
    print(rabin_karp(word, text))
    print(karp_rabin(word, text))
    verbose = False
    glob = globals()
    # have a look at timeit.Timer.repeat() and autorange(), too
    print(timeit.timeit('results = rabin_karp(word, text)',
                        globals=glob, number=9999))
    print(timeit.timeit('results = karp_rabin(word, text)',
                        globals=glob, number=9999))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! , i compared the two codes run time, and it's faster

Comment: Things. take. time.